# Facebook Comments not showing up in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook

Having an issue with the Facebook Comments Social Plugin - it works fine in FF and Chrome, but never shows up in IE 8.

I've stripped it down to the bare minimum, just in case there's a problem with my company's CMS - but it still doesn't show up in IE 8.

**Page is here:** http://www.idigbig.com/pages/fbcommenttest23.html

**Error in IE:**

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.1; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 22 Jun 2010 16:23:33 UTC
>
> Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object
>   Line: 11
>   Char: 5
>   Code: 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Add the attributes below to make it work on f.. IE :

```
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This answer just saved my sorry bum. For today.

Answer (score 2):

The aforementioned solution didn't work for me. My like and comments plugins wouldn't load and I'd had an error about missing braces.

However, this bizarre code fixes it:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?xfbml=1" type="text/javascript">

</script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(note the "?" and "#" difference in the URIs)